# having ... as an input variable

Tags: java

```
public ChartValue(String name, Color color, double ... values) {
        this.name = name;
        this.values = values;
        this.color = color;
    }
```

I am not quite sure the purpose of `double ... values`.

whats the difference between `double ... values` and `double values`

Comment: I think this is a very valid question... I don't know why someone would downvote that.  There are some decent answers already, so id check them out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`double...` means variable arguments.

What this means is that an unspecified number of scalar arguments can be passed in.

So I can call the method like

```
new ChartValue("blue", Color.BLUE, 1.2d, 5.8d, 6.05d, 100.0d)
```

In the constructor, it receives all of the doubles as just an array, so you can access it like

```
public ChartValue(String name, Color color, double ... values) {
    this.name = name;
    this.values = values;
    this.color = color;

    // at this point, "values" is just an array of doubles.
    System.out.println("Got " + values.length + " values.");
    for (double value : values) {
        System.out.println("Passed in " + value);
    }
}
```

This page has details:

https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2004/04/19/varargs.html

Note that you can only use one occurrence of varargs per method.  This will not compile:

```
public ChartValue(String name, Color... colors, double... values) {
    ...
}
```

because if you call it:

```
new ChartValue("blah", Color.BLUE, Color.ORANGE, 5.0d, 6.0d)
```

the compile doesn't know how to map the arguments in the method call to the parameters in the method definition.  The rule to make it work is that varargs must always be the last parameter and there can only be one.

Answer (score 5):

`double...` signifies that varargs are used by the argument.

The argument `double...` is syntactactic sugar for `double[] values`. The compiler does the actual translation at compile time. `double values` simply means that a single argument is being passed in the argument list.

`varargs` hava been in Java since version 1.5, Read more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html)

Comment: Can I call `test(1,2,3);` if the prototype is `void test(int[] values)` or does it only work the other way?

Comment: oh so double ... values is the same as double[] values. gotcha.

Comment: @Djon You can't call it that way if you're using `test(int[] values)` you would need to explicitly use a double array.

Answer (score 5):

`double...` means that the method will accept 0 or more double values. These will be places in values.

So `ChartValues("dude", Color.BLUE, 1.2, 1.5, 1.6)` would place 1.2, 1.5 and 1.6 into the variable values